# Decimal TryParse fails when a Decimal is entered

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have another question about the TryParse method I have created to check for my user's input. Sorry for my extra question, but I ran into another complication and wanted more assistance on it, so I made another question since my last one is quite old. I was afraid no one would see this question if I post it on the last one.

There are no errors, but when I try to run it to test what my user's input, for everything I enter, including whole numbers, decimals, (1.00, 1.0, 1,000.0) it gives me the Messagebox.Show anyway. Here's what I created:

```
    {
        // Arrange the variables to the correct TextBox.
        decimal Medical;

        if (!decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Medical))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal number.");
        }
        decimal Surgical;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Surgical))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal number.");
        }
        decimal Lab;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Lab))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal number.");
        }
        decimal Rehab;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Rehab))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a decimal number.");
        }

        // Find the cost of Miscs by adding the Misc Costs together.
        decimal MiscCharges = Medical + Surgical + Lab + Rehab;
        ChargeLabel.Text = MiscCharges.ToString("c");
```

In other words, I try to input any form of numbers on the Medical, Surgical, Lab, and Rehab textboxes and it still gives me the same MessageBox. Will someone provide me help on how to let my application check my user's input correctly? Thanks you, and sorry again.

Comment: please procide some input. It looks very likely that the input is not what you expect. So when you do procide the input make sure to get it from a debug session (not what you time in)

Comment: Just an observation, what happens if the user decides not to enter a decimal the second time around? e.g. the message box appears prompting for a decimal and the user decides against it ... is there no check done after the second prompt?

Comment: At what point are you making this checks? Maybe ChargeLabel.Text is empty?

Comment: Try commenting out all but one of the conditional checks, then setting a break point and actually looking at the value you're passing to the `TryParse`. Is it really a decimal? Are you retrieving the data from the correct spot?

Comment: @Sam Yes, the total MiscCharges show up in the ChargeLabel.Text property after I click this Button. But whatever I enter, numbers or letters it still shows the MessageBox.

Comment: @Cindy, is the MiscCharges value correct? Your code currently takes `ChargeLabel.Text`, parses it four times, then sums the same value four times before re-writing it to the same field. Perhaps the bug is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Drew, It's okay. I'll just not show messagebox for these variables. I think I'll just do a normal Parse for my variables and put it in its own TextBox.Text. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same label in each parsing statement.

```
decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Medical)
decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Surgical)
decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Lab)
decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Rehab)
```

**EDIT** I'd recommend putting a breakpoint in each `MessageBox.Show` line, then seeing what the string value you're parsing is.

You can also provide more information in the message shown:

```
decimal Rehab;
if (!decimal.TryParse(ChargeLabel.Text, out Rehab))
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Unable to parse '{0}' as a decimal number.", ChargeLabel.Text));
}
```

Comment: This is true, but can you explain a little more as to why this is the issue?

Comment: @Sam, it looks like a copy-and-paste error. Further, `ChargeLabel` is used to show the resulting sum. It's probably not the source of any of the values, let alone all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are entering numbers in a culture-correct format. Some cultures use comas as separators, others use dots. Try "123,4" and "123.4"

Comment: That didn't do it. I was hoping something like that would fix it. Still shows the MessageBox anyway. Thank you for telling me that though.